# How to convert a "Mmmm yyyy" string to a Date

Tags: r, date

I have dates as characters in the format of `January 2008`
I am trying to covert them to Date objects using `as.Date`. When I try this:

```
as.Date("January 2008", "%B %Y")
```

I am returned with `NA`. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Because January 2008 isn't a date. A date refers to a _day_. The **zoo** package will handle year-mon specifications (as will several other date/time packages, I believe.

Comment: @by0 just to add to what @joran's said, you need a month, day, and year to define a date. One option would be to add the day value to the date string with `paste`, e.g. `as.Date(paste("January 2008", "1"), "%B %Y %d")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so this has an official answer...

Month-Year doesn't specify a date, since you're missing a day. Several packages will handle Month-Year "dates". The ones I know of are **zoo** and **chron**. I suspected that **lubridate** will handle these as well, but as Hadley notes below in the comments, I was mistaken.

A Matthew mentioned, a possible hack is to artificially add a "dummy" day to each using `paste`.

Comment: Thank you! Prepending `1` to the characters worked! `as.Date("1 January 2008", "%d %B %Y")`

Comment: `lubridate` does not - it only uses existing base R structures (i.e. `POSIXct`) it doesn't add any new ones.